# HTTP Error 500.52 - URL Rewrite Module Error. name attribute

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis

I create an IIS express virtual directory in the property page of a web site. However, when I start to debug the website. it prompts the following error.

```
HTTP Error 500.52 - URL Rewrite Module Error.
Config Error       Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'rule' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'RequestBlockingRule1'
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have a section like this in your web.config:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>                
        <rule name="RequestBlockingRule1"
        ...
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

From the error it sounds like you have two  entries with the name set to "RequestBlockingRule1".